# How to choose which player is controlled by headphone button?

Tags: music-player, headphones

I have headphones, which has a button, which can stop/starts player applications. Unfortunately I also have several such players installed. Sometimes this button works well, but sometimes starts to control random player. Unneeded players can even not being run, but this button invokes them nevertheless. Is it possible to organize this?

Comment: You can use automation, [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) app. *Trigger*: Headphone inserted, *Action*: launch app ( your preferred media player), *Constraints*: none. See if that solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted, use a tool like MyAndroidTools to disable the broadcast receiver for `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` for unneeded apps that respond.

[image]